# How to assign value of a javascript variable to PHP Variable in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Have a code that takes the value of the customer in one page and post it to a PHP file as a javascript variable but from that page am not able to convert that variable to PHP Variable.

**Index.php**

```php
    document.getElementById("zoomingchart").src ="zoomingchart.php?Customername="+customer+"&EnvironmentType=BA";
```

**zoomingchart.php**

```php
    <script>
      function getParamValue(paramName)
      {
          var url = window.location.search.substring(1); 
          var qArray = url.split('&'); //get key-value pairs
          for (var i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) 
          {
              var pArr = qArray[i].split('='); //split key and value
              if (pArr[0] == paramName) 
                  return pArr[1]; //return value
          }
      }
      var param1 = getParamValue('Customername');
      var param2 = getParamValue('EnvironmentType');
      console.log(" "+param1+" "+param2+" ");
      
    </script>

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['EnvironmentType'])){
      $CustomerName = $_GET['Customername'];
      $EnvironmentType = $_GET['EnvironmentType'];
      
    }
?>
```

In zoomingchart.php when I give `console.log()` it prints the value of the environment variable and Customername but when I pass it to the PHP variable either it shows null or   gives error in this line

```
document.getElementById("zoomingchart").src ="zoomingchart.php?Customername="+customer+"&EnvironmentType=QA";
```

**and am getting this error :**
**

- GET
  http://localhost/Sreesha/zoomingchart.php?Customername=MDS&EnvironmentType=BA
  500 (Internal Server Error)

**

**on line in Index.php :**

```php
document.getElementById("zoomingchart").src ="zoomingchart.php?Customername="+customer+"&EnvironmentType=BA";
```

Comment: instead of console.log did you try var_dump($CustomerName) and see the result?

Comment: You should print all $_GET then you know what do you get: `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: It's unclear how index.php relates to the rest of your code.

Comment: i tried that too @Jerson

Comment: even that i tried @mihnsen

Comment: i am calling zoomingchart.php from index.php @ADyson

Comment: How about storing that variable in session ?

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's meaningless (deliberately so, for security), and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.